# JQuery Tipso position at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have tried many times to get tooltip tipso to show at the bottom, under the anchor, but can't get it working.

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery('.test').tipso({
  titleContent: 'Hello',
  showArrow:true,
  position :'bottom'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tipso/1.0.8/tipso.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tipso/1.0.8/tipso.css" />

<span class="test tipso_style" data-tipso="This is a Bottom TIPSO!">Bottom</span>
```

I want to use another class for each div but it never shows the tooltip under. I have set the position to bottom in  the configuration, I don´t understand why it doesn't work.

This is a simple question, because I have tested in many ways and never got it to display anywhere but at the top.

Thank's a lot for the help, best regards

Comment: when you read the question and understand only the last sentence :))

Comment: seems to work in the snippet i provided

Comment: The problem it´s with doctype if i don´t put <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">, no works , you can verificate